# why are some .NET methods written wrapped in brackets?

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests

I am new to programming and this might be a very elementary question, but I was wondering what items placed inside [brackets], such as [TestMethod] and [CodedUITest] are called and what their role is in .NET. Why is it that these methods are written in this manner?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968597/what-is-brackets-in-net

Comment: Have a look at [attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346/net-what-are-attributes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are called [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454.aspx). They give your code metadata the IDE can use to do things like know which methods are unit tests, how to serialize a class, or what to show first in intellisense prompts.

Comment: IDE and compiler and CLR and other stuff** :)

Answer (score 2):

They are Attributes

```
Attributes can be placed on most any declaration, though a 
specific attribute might restrict the types of declarations on which it is valid.
In C#, you specify an attribute by placing the name of the attribute, enclosed in square brackets ([]), above 
the declaration of the entity to which it applies. In Visual Basic, an attribute
is enclosed in angle brackets (< >). It must appear immediately before the element to
```

which it is applied, 
    on the same line.

[Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)

[Introduction to Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)